# Hadoop Permission denied on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop in order to use the HDFS service. I'm doing it in the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (not VM) :

https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

The tutorial that I followed was this one (which is really similar to most tutorials for Hadoop installation):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb1sinaTlmo

So everything goes well until I try to run the `start-dfs.sh` but I get this error messages:

```
17/12/12 22:19:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-DESKTOP-QG5RB4T.out
localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-DESKTOP-QG5RB4T.out
localhost: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-DESKTOP-QG5RB4T.out
0.0.0.0: nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
17/12/12 22:19:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I made sure that the `ssh localhost` worked, also I gave permission to the hadoop folder `chmod -R 755 hadoop/` and also give root privileges to the user I created for doing the hadoop implementation.

If you have any leads or solutions for this problem it would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem and for the love of god, I can't figure it out.

It has been like 2 Months and still nothing helps. I asked so many professionals and they can't figure it out themselves too.

The only tip I received is to check my Windows SSH Broker and disable it, but as far as I tried, it can't be done, cause it's an integral part to Windows. You can only partially disable it, which changes absolutely nothing.

I hope you can find the solution for the problem and I'm sorry that I can't help you with that any further, but I would be soo glad to know the solution to this aswell.

Comment: it seems that the only way is installing a real Linux VM :(

Comment: @alohapinilla did you manage to solve it this way?

The weird thing is, other people I know did the same things and it works for them, so it definitely should work, but I don't know why it doesn't... 

This is just so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/passwd file, giving {hadoop} user root permissions (replacing 1001 values with 0)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can see this answer: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/issues/695#issuecomment-386121530.
It says "You can safely ignore this warning. It's an upstream bug in Microsoft Windows."